# Switch statement only returns the default case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Can someone help me understand, why is my switch case returning the default value. Even when I change all values it only returns the default at first I thought it was a hoisting issue in my code but after debugging it's I found it's the statement, it ignores all other cases. (p.s please don't be mean I just want to understand, the other examples I've seen aren't simply explained and don't have much up votes so I did try.)

```js
var shippingMethod = document.querySelector("[name=r_method]:checked").value;
var shippingChoice;


switch(shippingMethod) {
    case "usps":
        shippingChoice = 2;
        break;
    case "ups":
        shippingChoice = 3;
        break;
    default:
        shippingChoice = 0;
        break;
}
console.log(shippingChoice);
```

Comment: You seem to have defined the variable `shippingMethod` as undefined.

Comment: Also your `case "usps":` sets the same value as the default.

Comment: I figured it was bad form to fix the problem in a question edit, but to the OP: feel free to assign shippingMethod a value first, like `"ups"` and see how the snippet runs.

Comment: okay thank you I'll try that also the shipping method                                                    
 var shippingMethod = document.querySelector("[name=r_method]:checked").value;

Comment: Does this code exist in a function that's called when the input's value changes?

Comment: sorry about the wrong "usps" value.. I was debugging it was set to 0 initially. maybe I should just use a if statement?

Comment: An if statement wouldn't help here. You'd only have the same issue.

Comment: @danh when I hardcode the values "ups"/"usps" to the shippingMethod the case results do change... so maybe I'm using the querySelector wrong? still it's a step in the right direction thanks alot I'll try and figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: When are you getting the input value? How are you getting the value once it's changed by a user?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the "[name=r_method]" is the name for my radio inputs and the ":checked" part takes the value of the checked radio input... its the same as CSS, it copies the value of the checked radio. should I post the html snippet also?

Comment: The selector is fine. I'm just making sure you're aware that it will only get the value when the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an if statement to verify there is a value for shippingMethod. As well, when querying for the value, make sure to include quote ("") around the value of the name.

```js
var shippingMethod = "default";
var shippingChoice;

if (document.querySelector('[name="r_method"]:checked') != null)
{
  shippingMethod = document.querySelector('[name="r_method"]:checked').value;
}

switch(shippingMethod) {
    case "usps":
        shippingChoice = 2;
        break;
    case "ups":
        shippingChoice = 3;
        break;
    default:
        shippingChoice = 0;
        break;
}
console.log(shippingChoice);
```